# Associativity and truncatedness of a $\mathbb N$-filtered object

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

$\require{AMScd}$Consider the monoid monad: $S : Set \to Set$ sends a set $X$ to the free monoid on $X$:
$$
SX := \coprod_{n\in\mathbb N} X^n
$$ the empty sequence $()\in X^0$ is the identity element for the concatenation operation $X^n\times X^m \to X^{n+m}$.

Now, what is an algebra for this monad? It is a set $M$, with a map $a : SM\to M$ such that axioms hold. But then such $a$ corresponds to a family of maps
$$
(a_n : X^n \to X \mid n \in\mathbb N )
$$ prescribing an $n$-ary operation on $X$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$.

However, now, all $a_n$ for $n\ge 3$ are determined by $a_0,a_1,a_2$ and their composite, because the associativity axiom for $a$ now implies that $a_n$ has a unique reduction/rewriting as a composition
$$
(w_1\times\cdots\times w_n)\circ (w_1\times\cdots\times w_{n-1}) \circ \cdots\circ (w_1\times w_2)\circ a_2
$$
For example, $a_3 : X\times X \times X \to X$ must be either $(a_2\times 1)\circ a_2$ or $(1\times a_2)\circ a_2$; the two are equal, by the very statement of associativity. And $a_4$ is 
$$
(1\times a_3)\circ a_3 = (1 \times ((a_2\times 1)\circ a_2))\circ ((a_2\times 1)\circ a_2)
$$
or 
$$
(a_3\times 1)\circ a_3 = (((1\times a_2)\circ a_2)\times 1)\circ ((1\times a_2)\circ a_2)
$$ These are equal, again by associativity.

So,

> From the very shape of the monad, we have been able to deduce that an algebra structure is completely determined by $a_{\le 2}$.

This is an interesting and distinctive property of semigroups/monoids over other kinds of nonassociative structures: if we represent the composition of a tuple under a binary operation as a tree (whose root is the full composition of the tuple), of course different parenthesizations give different results. This is reflected in the shape of the monad of magmas (whose algebras are sets with a closed binary operation $m : X\times X \to X$), 
$$
\begin{cases}
(MX)_0 := X\\
(MX)_n := \sum_{p+q=n} (MX)_p \times (MX)_q \\
MX := \sum_{n\in\mathbb N} (MX)_n 
\end{cases}
$$ There is no $n$ that determines $MX$ completely; something that follows from the definition of magma, of course, *but also from the very shape of the monad that has magmas as algebras*.

> Let me try to formalise better what it means "determine completely" a structure: let again $S$ be the monoid monad, and let us consider the $\mathbb N$-indexed set
>   $$
> \begin{CD}
> \coprod_{n\in\mathbb N} X^n \\
> @VpVV\\
> \mathbb N
> \end{CD}
> $$ the fibers $p^{-1}n$ for $n\ge 3$ now are "uniquely determined" by $p^{-1}\{0,1,2\}$ in the sense that each element in $u\in p^{-1}n$ is a unique push-forward $p_*\bar u$ of an element $\bar u\in p^{-1}\{0,1,2\}$. This is the "truncatedness" condition we were looking for.

All this consists of very elementary observations, I am clearly rediscovering the wheel; and yet I have never seen it worded out explicitly in terms of a truncatedness condition.

I am clearly looking in the wrong place though, because the more I think about it, then, the more I feel inclined to link it to Mac Lane's coherence theorem for monoidal categories ("all diagrams commute" if you give me unitor and associator), and to another kind of important internal monoids we all work with: categories (once you specify binary compositions in a 2-coskeletal quasicategory, i.e. a category, you specify it everywhere).

So, questions:

1. What's going on here? *What is* the property of $S$ that $M$ does not have, and that makes it possible to determine an algebra structure on just some $a_n$? Maybe my above argument can be formalised. If so, how?
2. What is the relation between this statement, and other "truncatedness" conditions on monoid-like structures?

Comment: I don't see why your two examples should be different in the way you describe. The action map $M(X) \to X$ of a magma is also completely determined by the restruction $M_2(X) \to X$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it is not exactly what I wanted to say. Any clue on the final questions?

Comment: What do you mean by "the shape of the monad"? Does this refer to the underlying endofunctor?